# Browsing hdfs not work

Tags: hdfs, namenode

I installed HDFS using Cloudera Manager 5 . Then i tried to browse http://localhost:50070/ (Hdfshealth) it was not working !
please help !

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

In your question, you are saying that you are browsing Hadoop. Does that mean you are listing hadoop file system? 50070 is a default namenode port so try to access Cloudera manager on port 7180.